# find the (infinity norm) condition number of the following matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

> How can I find the (infirmity norm) condition number of the following matrix?
>   $$A =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\2&4.001\end{bmatrix}$$

Looking for some guidance on how to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you mean the infinity norm?  If not, we need a definition of the infirmity norm.

Comment: What do you know about condition numbers and the infinity norm? Have you tried working with the definitions?

Comment: yes infinity norm

Comment: @GEdgar well of course if a matrix is ill-conditioned, we say it's infirm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that means infinity norm

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ 2 & 4.001 \end{bmatrix} \tag{1} $$

$$ \| A\|_{\infty} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq m } \| a_{i}^{*} \|_{1} \tag{2} $$

the $\infty $ norm is equal to the max row sum. So $a_{i}^{*}$ denotes the $ith$ row

then we have

$$ \|a_{1}^{*}|| = 3  \\  \| a_{2}^{*}|| = 6.001 $$

$$ \|A\|_{\infty} = 6.001  \tag{3}$$

```
import numpy as np
import math


A = np.matrix([[1 ,2],[2, 4.001 ]])
Ainf = np.linalg.norm(A,np.inf)

Ainf
Out[5]: 6.001
```

This is an example matrix of an ill-conditioned matrix apparently

```
Acond = np.linalg.cond(A)

A1 = np.matrix([[1 ,2],[2, 4.000 ]])
A1cond = np.linalg.cond(A1)

Acond
Out[8]: 250008.00009210614

A1cond
Out[9]: 2.517588727560788e+16
```

If we create a slight perturbation it is massively ill-conditioned.

Note that

$$ \kappa(A) = \| A \| \| A^{-1}\| \tag{4} $$

using the $\infty $ norm

we take the inverse

$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{4.001-4.00}\begin{bmatrix} 4.001 & -2 \\ -2 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \tag{5} $$ 
$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{0.001}\begin{bmatrix} 4.001 & -2 \\ -2 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \tag{6} $$

if you see here where the problem is where you invert the matrix
$$ A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 4001.000 & -2000 \\ -2000 & 1000  \end{bmatrix} \tag{7} $$

then we take $\infty$ norm

$$ \kappa(A) = 6.001 \cdot 6001 \approx 36000 \tag{6}$$

Note that

$$\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} = 6001 \tag{7}$$

because it has max absolute value

See here

```
np.linalg.cond(A,np.inf)
Out[30]: 36012.00099998798
```

### Eigenvalues

$$ det(A - \lambda I ) = det \bigg( \begin{bmatrix} 1 - \lambda  & 2  \\ 2 & 4.00-\lambda+\epsilon \end{bmatrix} \bigg)  \tag{8}$$

$$ det(A - \lambda I )  = (1-\lambda)(4.00-\lambda+\epsilon) -4 \tag{9}$$

$$ det(A - \lambda I )  = \lambda^{2} -5\lambda + \epsilon - \epsilon \lambda  \tag{10}$$

Can you continue from there? I was on this path because

$$ \kappa(A) = \frac{\lambda_{max}(A)}{\lambda_{min}(A)} \tag{11} $$

there are only two eigenvalues..this isn't exactly for the $\infty$ norm

If  $\epsilon =0$

$$ det(A - \lambda I )  = \lambda^{2} -5\lambda  \implies \lambda_{1} =5 \lambda_{2} =0   \tag{12}$$

what is that ratio.

### On Ill-Conditioning

Ill-Conditioning is most understood perhaps when you have an algorithm that isn't backwards stable like classical gram Schmidt.

```
function qrcgs(A)
# Classical Gram Schmidt for an m x n matrix 

(m,n) = size(A) 
# Generates the Q, R matrices
Q = zeros(m,n) 
R = zeros(n,n)
    for k = 1:n
        # Assign the vector for normalization
        w = A[:,k]
        for j=1:k-1
            # Gets R entries
            R[j,k] = Q[:,j]'*w
        end

        for j = 1:k-1
           # Subtracts off orthogonal projections 
           w = w-R[j,k]*Q[:,j]
        end
        # Normalize 
        R[k,k] = norm(w)
        Q[:,k] = w./R[k,k]
    end

    return Q,R
end 

function generate_matrix(eps)
# generates matrix

    matrix = [[ 1 2];[2 4+eps] ]

    return matrix

end   

function backsub(R,b)
# Backsub for upper triangular matrix.
(m,n) = size(R)
p = min(m,n)
x  = zeros(n,1)

    for i=p:-1:1
        # Look from bottom, assign to vector
        r = b[i]
        for j=i+1:p
            # Subtract off the difference
            r = r-R[i,j]*x[j]
        end
        x[i] = r/R[i,i]
    end

    return x
end 

mu = 1e-5

my_matrix = generate_matrix(mu)

2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0    
 2.0  4.00001

x = ones(2)

b = my_matrix*x
```

if I take $Ax=b$ and solve $QRx=b$ and find the relative error $\frac{\| \hat{x} -x\|}{\|x\|}  $ when you do $Rx = Q^{-1}b $

```
Q,R = qrcgs(my_matrix)

b1 = Q'*b
x1 = backsub(R,b1)
x2 = norm(x1-x)/norm(x)

0.0003159759388686106
```

the closer $\epsilon $ is to $0$ the worse this error is because **the more ill-conditioned we are. We are losing more precision.**

See if I make $\mu = 1e-10$

```
mu = 1e-10
```

I get massive error, my $\hat{x}$ comes out like this

```
2×1 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.33203e10
 -6.66015e9
```

it is supposed to be

```
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.0
```

so my error is

```
1.0530625888158983e10
```

Comment: why is $a_1=3$ but $a_2$ is only $4.001$?

Comment: i screwed up one moment

Comment: would this be well-conditioned or ill-conditioned then?

Comment: visually looking at, sometimes I remember example matrices like this where you add .00001 and it becomes ill-conditioned

Comment: the computer says it is moderately ill-condtioned

Comment: is there a reason for this?

Comment: If you do the eigenvalues decomp of this matrix out by hand you'll have an answer .

Comment: how would I find that? could you edit that in

Comment: how would I do the eigenvalue decomp?

Comment: working on that one moment

Comment: Are you sure of A1? I read 4.000, it must be 4.001, no?

Comment: A1 is an example matrix that is separate from A to show that if you pertub it then the condition number blows up

Comment: note that the condition number is $1e16$ it happens because when you invert you matrix

Comment: I am confused to what is the answer, 6.001 or 120000?

Comment: also in your first matrix you have 4.0001 it is 4.001

Comment: the infty norm $\|A\|_{\infty}$ is 6.001 however the condition number $\kappa(A) = \|A\|_{\infty} \|A^{-1} \|_{\infty}$  so it is 6.0001 times the inverted matrixs infinity norm

Comment: oh I have tooo many zeros

Comment: I see so I need to include both, what about the reasoning behind it being ill conditioned?

Comment: you do not have to include both. I just felt like it. The reasoning is when you inverting that matrix see line 6

Comment: if you subtract $4.001 -4$ and it gets closer together then you divide by that it gets very large

Comment: okay gotcha, what about the eigenvalue calculation for the reasoning behind it being ill-conditioned

Comment: I thought you were going to show the written version of the explanation, not the programming

Comment: lines 4-9 are all explaining what is happening

Comment: what is $\in$ how do I solve that eigenvalue?

Comment: $\epsilon $ is whatever you are adding to $4.00$  just put it in wolfram. .

Comment: okay, could you finish that explanation?

Comment: is 0 a bad thing?

Comment: well it doesn't exist as a ratio. but if you derive further you'd see that if you like take the limit as $\epsilon$ goes to 0 then $\kappa(A)$ blows up right.

Comment: okay so it doesn't exist we can say that is the reason why it is ill conditioned?

Comment: No, I believe we say matrices with a condition number of over like 30000 are ill-conditioned.

Comment: it is more about the numerical error that will produced when you use some types of algorithms.

Comment: algorithms that aren't backwards stable

Comment: oh I see that's why you did the condition number, to find if it was ill conditoned

Comment: Well mostly because your question says to find the condition number so I did.

Comment: i was confused with the question, whether to find an infinity norm or condition number, or if they are the same thing

Comment: well as you see the condition number could have any norm this one required the  infinity norm.

Comment: okay well thanks for everything!

Comment: I am still a little confused to why it is ill conditioned tho

Comment: have you taken numerical analysis?

Comment: that is what I am taking right now

Comment: one moment let me write some

Comment: okay if you could explain the reasoning behind that that would be great!